# boto3 throws error in when packaged under rpm

Tags: amazon-web-services, rpm, boto3

I am using boto3 in my project and when i package it as rpm it is raising error while initializing ec2 client.

```
<class 'botocore.exceptions.DataNotFoundError'>:Unable to load data for: _endpoints. Traceback -Traceback (most recent call last):
File "roboClientLib/boto/awsDRLib.py", line 186, in _get_ec2_client
File "boto3/__init__.py", line 79, in client
File "boto3/session.py", line 200, in client
File "botocore/session.py", line 789, in create_client
File "botocore/session.py", line 682, in get_component
File "botocore/session.py", line 809, in get_component
File "botocore/session.py", line 179, in <lambda>
File "botocore/session.py", line 475, in get_data
File "botocore/loaders.py", line 119, in _wrapper
File "botocore/loaders.py", line 377, in load_data
DataNotFoundError: Unable to load data for: _endpoints
```

Can anyone help me here. Probably boto3 requires some run time resolutions which it not able to get this in rpm.

I tried with using LD_LIBRARY_PATH in /etc/environment which is not working.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto3:/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto3-1.2.3.dist-info:/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/botocore:
```

Comment: also throws error when packaged as `zip`. I guess `aws` SDK isn't happy with getting *packaged*

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue:

> botocore.exceptions.DataNotFoundError: Unable to load data for: ec2/2016-04-01/service-2

For which I figured out the directory was missing. Updating `botocore` by running the following solved my issue:

```
pip install --upgrade botocore
```

Answer (score 0):

Botocore depends on a set of [service definition files](https://github.com/boto/botocore/tree/develop/botocore/data) that it uses to generate clients on the fly. Boto3 further depends on [another set of files](https://github.com/boto/boto3/tree/develop/boto3/data) that it uses to generate resource clients. You will need to include these in any installs of boto3 or botocore. The files will need to be located in the 'data' folder of the root of the respective library.

Comment: Thanks. i used .egg(installed using easy_install utility) and my make file automatically included while boto3 including data files into RPM.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue which was due to old version of botocore. Once I updated it, it started working.

Please consider using below command.

**pip install --upgrade botocore**

Also please ensure, you have setup boto configuration profile.

Boto searches credentials in below order.

- Passing credentials as parameters in the boto.client() method
- Passing credentials as parameters when creating a Session object
- Environment variables
- Shared credential file (~/.aws/credentials)
- AWS config file (~/.aws/config)
- Assume Role provider
- Boto2 config file (/etc/boto.cfg and ~/.boto)
- Instance metadata service on an Amazon EC2 instance that has an IAM
  role configured.